# How do we run tmux from ssh agent using python

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu, ssh

how do we create a tmux session using python based ssh client programs?

```
from pssh.clients import ParallelSSHClient



def Estabish_Connection(host,username,passkey):
    client = ParallelSSHClient([str(host)],user=str(username), password=str(passkey))
    return client


client2 = Estabish_Connection('host','root','password')

cmd_out = client2.run_command('tmux new -s myname')

for host,out in cmd_out.items():
    for line in out.stdout:
        print(line)
```

It doesn't create a tmux window on checking manually from a terminal.

```
> tmux ls
no server running on /tmp/tmux-0/default
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`open terminal failed: not a terminal`

Okay well post the tmux bits of the script, by default it will try to attach to the current tty (which doesn't exist hence the error) if you have a new session in there for example you'll need to add a -d param to prevent this

`tmux new-session -s username -d`